# Is a function-valued matrix analytic if its entries are analystic functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $\boldsymbol{A}(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a function valued Hermitian matrix. If the entries $a_{ij}(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{C}$ of  $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$ are analytic functions is $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$ also analytic?

Comment: Dont you mean "Hermitian matrix valued function"? What is the definition of a analytic matrix valued function? Identical with its Taylor series? If yes, I would say this is trivially fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, it is trivial. Whenever $a_{ij} (t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{ijk} t^k$ then the matrix can be also written as infinite sum, like

$A(t) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \begin{bmatrix} c_{11k} & \dots & c_{1nk} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ c_{n1k} & \dots & c_{nnk} \end{bmatrix} t^k$

It also looks like $A(t)$ doesn't have to be Hermitian.